# How does the random func works in sqlalchemy in python (for MySQL databse)?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I did not find any answer in the doc so I ask you for help. I want to generate a random response from my database. To be reproducible, I set the seed and call a simple query this way:

```
func.setseed(0)
session.query(MyModel.id).order_by(func.random()).first()  #  --> returns 324
func.setseed(0)
session.query(MyModel.id).order_by(func.random()).first()  #  --> returns 736
```

As you can see, even after resetting the seed, the result is still different. However, I found a way to fix it, but I dont understand why:

```
func.setseed(0)
session.query(MyModel.id).order_by(func.random(0.1)).first()  #  --> returns 547
func.setseed(0)
session.query(MyModel.id).order_by(func.random(0.1)).first()  #  --> returns 547
```

What does the func.random argument mean ?

Comment: Did you actually execute `func.setseed(0)`? In your example you don't. `func.setseed(0)` just creates a function expression object. It is rendered to suitable SQL when compiled and executed as a part of a query.

Answer (score 1):

The `func.random` is actually a `sqlalchemy.sql.functions.GenericFunction`, which is a generic method that is not database-specific.

On a MySQL database, the argument passed to the random function acts as the seed - that's why it returns the same value.

You can read more about it [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/functions.html) and [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/functions.html?highlight=random#sqlalchemy.sql.functions.GenericFunction)

Comment: Thanks. My concerns was about the argument of the rand function, and why the setseed seemed to have no effect. The MySQL doc about the rand function is ambiguous as the argument is said to be a integer but later its description is a number between 0 and 1. I tried both and no exception was raised.